# bookshelf.js transaction not working with attach

Tags: bookshelf.js

Appreciate any help that you can provide.

I'm trying to create a 'Runway' model then attach 'Model' IDs for a many-to-many relationship within a transaction.

The model is still created when an error is thrown during attach (i.e. the transaction is not rolled back). What am I doing wrong?

```
export function create(object) {
  var data = _.pick(object, ['name', 'userId']);

  return Bookshelf.transaction((t) => {
    return Runway.forge(data)
      .save(null, {transaction: t})
      .then((runway) => {
          return runway.models().attach(object.models, {transaction: t});
      })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    winston.error('Error creating runway', {err: err});
    throw err;
  });
}
```

Logs:

```
Mon, 10 Oct 2016 06:07:59 GMT knex:tx trx1: Starting top level transaction
{ method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: 
   [ 2016-10-10T06:07:59.769Z,
     'bf649bbf-c37f-426a-98e3-707e49eb17c6',
     'my custom runway',
     2016-10-10T06:07:59.769Z,
     '66da84f6-45f4-4217-a995-dfb92cb246f1' ],
  __knexQueryUid: 'c54606e4-7e4c-4a04-b66b-2f747df1ad6d',
  sql: 'insert into `runways` (`created_at`, `id`, `name`, `updated_at`, `userId`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' }
{ method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: 
   [ 'f0a3bc21-2315-4b83-9cac-bab1fc019f1555',
     'bf649bbf-c37f-426a-98e3-707e49eb17c6' ],
  __knexQueryUid: '6125efce-3ef4-4327-a4ed-445634a26057',
  sql: 'insert into `runways_models` (`modelId`, `runwayId`) values (?, ?)' }
Mon, 10 Oct 2016 06:07:59 GMT knex:tx trx1: releasing connection
2016-10-10T06:07:59.815Z ERROR [winston-fh] Error creating runway [METADATA]: {"err":{"message":"insert into `runways_models` (`modelId`, `runwayId`) values ('f0a3bc21-2315-4b83-9cac-bab1fc019f1555', 'bf649bbf-c37f-426a-98e3-707e49eb17c6') - ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`figurehappy`.`runways_models`, CONSTRAINT `runways_models_modelid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`modelId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))","stack":"Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`figurehappy`.`runways_models`, CONSTRAINT `runways_models_modelid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`modelId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))\n    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:51:14)\n    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)\n    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)\n    at Parser.write (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)\n    at Protocol.write (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:177:18)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:135:10)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20)\n    --------------------\n    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)\n    at Connection.query (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)\n    at /Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:124:18\n    at Promise._execute (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:284:9)\n    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:480:18)\n    at new Promise (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)\n    at Client._query (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:118:12)\n    at Client.query (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:187:24)\n    at Runner.<anonymous> (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:129:36)\n    at Runner.tryCatcher (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Runner.query (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:15:34)\n    at /Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:55:21\n    at tryCatcher (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at /Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:185:26\n    at tryCatcher (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:509:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)\n    at Promise._fulfill (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:635:18)\n    at PromiseArray._resolve (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:125:19)\n    at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:143:14)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:571:26)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)\n    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)\n    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/Nim/Workspace/figurehappy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)\n    at runCallback (timers.js:570:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:550:5)\n    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:529:5)","code":"ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2","errno":1452,"sqlState":"23000","index":0}}

insert into `runways_models` (`modelId`, `runwayId`) values ('f0a3bc21-2315-4b83-9cac-bab1fc019f1555', 'bf649bbf-c37f-426a-98e3-707e49eb17c6') - ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`figurehappy`.`runways_models`, CONSTRAINT `runways_models_modelid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`modelId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`figurehappy`.`runways_models`, CONSTRAINT `runways_models_modelid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`modelId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... this was a User error.

I should have written {transacting: t} instead of {transaction: t}.